# Get more details in JSON with feed request

Tags: android, json, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using Facebook SDK for android devices. I want all the informations of every post (created time, id, message, imagelink and link). This is my code:

```
 Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
 parameters.putString("limit", "100");
 final String[]cmb=new String[100];
            new GraphRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    "/GAMETIMETV/feed",
                    parameters,
                    HttpMethod.GET,
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {

                            JSONObject json = response.getJSONObject();
                            String[] cmb= new String[100];
                            try {

                                JSONArray arrayId = json.getJSONArray("data");


                                for(int y=0;y<arrayId.length();y++){
                                    cmb[y]=arrayId.getJSONObject(y).getString("id"); //id from json to String array
                                }


                                Bundle parametri = new Bundle();
                                parametri.putString("fields", "link,attachments{media{image}}");    //parameters of the request 

                                for(int i =0;i<cmb.length;i++) {


                                    new GraphRequest(
                                            AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                                            "/" + cmb[i].id,
                                            parametri,
                                            HttpMethod.GET,
                                            new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                                                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {


                                                }
                                            }).executeAsync();
                                }


                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }).executeAsync();
```

This code is heavy, can I have post link and image link without doing another request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can combine this into one API call:

```
/GAMETIMETV/feed?limit=100&fields=message,created_time,link,attachments{media{image}}
```

...or like this in your code:

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("limit", "100");
parameters.putString("fields", "message,created_time,link,attachments{media{image}}");
```